# In .net onblur event display message in label, is it possible

Tags: asp.net, javascript

i have two textboxs, without enter the values in first tetxbox when iam going to second textbox it showing the message in label beside textbox . is it possible in dotnet, i don't want alert message , i want show that message in label.

i have written code ,using javascript iam display the alert message in  onblur event.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a RequiredFieldValidator control for that.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="rqField1"
   ControlToValidate = "ID of input control to validate"
   InitialValue = "" 
   ErrorMessage = "message to display in ValidationSummary control"
   Text = "message to display in control"
   runat="server" />
```

See

**[HOW TO: Use the RequiredFieldValidator Control with Other Validation Controls to Handle Blank Entries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313044)**

jQuery based solution

```
$(function(){
            $("#txt1").bind("blur", function(){
                var val = $.trim($(this).val());
                if ( val === "" )
                {
                    $("#spnError").show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#spnError").hide();   
                }
            });
        });

<span id="spnError" style="display: none">Please enter valid input</span>
        <input type="text" id="txt1" />
        <input type="text" id="txt2" />
```

Comment: required field validator working only after submit the form, i want display that message moving to second textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `onblur` event to first textbox in `Page_Load`

```
textbox1.Attributes.Add("onblur","validate()");
```

Implement `validate` method in your aspx file as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(){
 //Do validation , show messages etc
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Test(txt, label)
{
    if (txt.value == "")
        label.innerHTML = "Wrong Value";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" onblur="Test(this, lbl1);"/>
    <label id="lbl1" for="txt1">SomeVal</label>
</body>
```